# Permutation of a list Python

Tags: python, permutation, point

I am trying to append all possible permutations of the list, candidates, to the list called res. The list res is supposed to be [[1,1]. [1,2], [2,1],[2,2]]. But it only returns [[], [], [],[]]. I tried to run the debugger. It turns out that when it pops the element of curr, the sub-list of res will also be popped. (I can fix it by using res.append(curr.copy()) )

Why will that happen?

```
candidates = [1, 2]
res = []

def backtracking(curr):
    if len(curr) == len(candidates):
        res.append(curr)
        return
    else:
        for i in range(len(candidates)):
            curr.append(candidates[i])
            backtracking(curr)
            curr.pop()

backtracking([])
print(res)
```

Comment: Try list(itertools.product([1,2],repeat=2))

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is called the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

*Permutations* of `[1, 2]` are `[(1, 2), (2, 1)]` but not `(1, 1)` or `(2, 2)`.

*Combinations* of `[1, 2]` are `[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]`; close but missing `(2, 1)`.

You could accomplish this using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.product([1,2], repeat=2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Python lists are (mutable) object references.  So when you assign a list to a variable or pass it as a parameter, all variables are referencing the same object instance. So any change (including pop) will be seen by all references.  The `.copy()` method creates a separate instance of the list with a copy of its content.  This copy is independent of the original and changes to it will not be reflected to other variables that still reference the original. Also, changes to the original will not affect the copy.